# What is `where .force`?

Tags: stream, agda

I've been playing around with the idea of writing programs that run on Streams and properties with them, but I feel that I am stuck even with the simplest of things. When I look at the definition of `repeat` in `Codata/Streams` in the standard library, I find a construction that I haven't seen anywhere in Agda: `λ where .force →`.

Here, an excerpt of a Stream defined with this weird feature:

```
repeat : ∀ {i} → A → Stream A i
repeat a = a ∷ λ where .force → repeat a
```

Why does `where` appear in the middle of the lambda function definition?, and what is the purpose of `.force` if it is never used?

I might be asking something that is in the documentation, but I can't figure out how to search for it.

Also, is there a place where I can find documentation to use "Codata" and proofs with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> Why does where appear in the middle of the lambda function definition?,

Quoting [the docs](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1/language/lambda-abstraction.html):

> Anonymous pattern matching functions can be defined using one of the
> two following syntaxes:
>
> `\ { p11 .. p1n -> e1 ; … ; pm1 .. pmn -> em }`
>
> `\ where   p11 .. p1n -> e1   …   pm1 .. pmn -> em`

So `λ where` is an anonymous pattern matching function. `force` is the field of [`Thunk`](https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/14577d5f187329c8eef5997b5bc2d30af1955aad/src/Codata/Thunk.agda#L17) and `.force` is a [copattern](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1/language/copatterns.html) in postfix notation (originally I said nonsense here, but thanks to @**Cactus** it's now fixed, see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63013330/3237465)).

> Also, is there a place where I can find documentation to use "Codata" and proofs with it? Thanks!

Check out these papers

1. [Normalization by Evaluation in the Delay Monad
   A Case Study for Coinduction via Copatterns and Sized Types](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2059)
2. [Equational Reasoning about Formal Languages in Coalgebraic Style](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Eabela/jlamp17.pdf)
3. [Guarded Recursion in Agda via Sized Types](https://cs.ru.nl/%7Enweide/AgdaSizedTypes.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

As one can see in the definition of `Thunk`, `force` is the *field* of the `Thunk` record type:

```
record Thunk {ℓ} (F : Size → Set ℓ) (i : Size) : Set ℓ where
  coinductive
  field force : {j : Size< i} → F j
```

So in the pattern-matching lambda, `.force` is not a dot pattern (why would it be? there is nothing prescribing the value of the parameter), but instead is simply syntax for the record field selector `force`. So the above code is equivalent to making a record with a single field called `force` with the given value, using [copatterns](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.3/language/copatterns.html#copatterns):

```
repeat a = a :: as
  where
    force as = repeat a
```

or, which is actually where the `.force` syntax comes from, using postfix projection syntax:

```
repeat a = a :: as
  where
    as .force = repeat a
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for fixing my mistake. I'll delete my nonsense and link to your answer instead.

Comment: After reading about "copatterns" the code makes a lot more sense. Still, I am unable to run the variations you showed. I am uncertain on the type of `as`. Is it `∀ {i} → Thunk (Stream A i)`? Also, I tried yet another variation (I think) but it fails to "compile" `repeat a = a ∷ record {force = repeat a}`. Is it possible to use a record in this case?